# How to display one to one correspondence for all bit strings not containing the bit O?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

This is a problem from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications 
[image]

From the onset I saw that this set was countable was that you could physically count these out - 1, 11, 111, 1111  and perhaps create a function that mapped from Z+ to set A where set A is the set of all bit strings not containing the bit 0.

The author did something similar in another example - 
[image]

and later showed the one to correspondence between the two sets by showing that the function is onto and one to one. In this case, would the function approach be appropriate? Or are you supposed to list them out in like a map like in the rational numbers example? If the function approach is appropriate, how would you mathematically define the function and show that it is one to one and onto?

Comment: Either way is good. Writing $$f(n)=11\dots1\qquad (n\,1's)$$is certainly more compact.

Comment: i would agree that is more compact but how would you show that function is onto and one to one though?